# How can I use keypress and prompt libraries same time?

Tags: node.js, keypress, prompt

I want to catch all [key presses](https://github.com/TooTallNate/keypress), but also, use [`prompt` library](https://github.com/flatiron/prompt).

```
var Prompt = require("prompt")
  , Keypress = require("keypress")
  ;

Prompt.start();
var schema = {
    properties: {
        name: {
            required: true
          , description: "What's your name?"
        }
    }
};

Prompt.get(schema, function (err, result) {
    console.log(err || result);
});

process.stdin.on("keypress", function (ch, key) {
    console.log(key);
    if (key && key.name === "c" && key.ctrl) {
        process.exit();
    }
});
```

The issue is that after `prompt` callback is called, `keypress` events are not triggered anymore.

Is there a solution/work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following workaround:

```
// Override get method
var oldGet = Prompt.get;
Prompt.get = function (schema, callback) {
    oldGet.call(this, schema, function () {
        process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
        process.stdin.resume();
        callback.apply(this, arguments);
    });
};
```

I [used this](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/cli-github/blob/a1c0cece9bb9db86f6ff47dd4f2c839cf90755fb/bin/github#L29-L37) in the [`cli-github`](http://ionicabizau.net/blog/15-cli-github-a-fancy-github-client-for-command-line) project.